# Will the yellow stain from prodiamine come off of white landscape stone?

Tags: herbicide

I hired landscapers to do a ton of work at my house and one part was to fill a very large area with white landscape stone. Contract stated they would put paper under it then the stone. They did not put the paper down and with one storm weeds came up through the stone, so I complained. The landscaper applied prodiamine (I think this is the correct name?) on the stone and said on his way out "it came out a little heavy in the one area and you'll see the stone is a little yellow; you can hit that with some water from the hose and it'll come right off." Didn't say when to spray it (then or wait a few days). So I went outside and it was blinding neon yellow in one large area and then less yellow but still discolored going in spray patterns all over the rest of the stone. I was in shock--so I did what he said--hit the worst area a little with the hose--it doesn't budge. I emailed him and he said don't spray it, just bear with him, he sprays this all the time on patios and walkways, not to worry, the yellow is just the chemical and he'll stop by tomorrow to explain how it works. But so far I can't find anything online that assures me this won't leave a permanent stain. It's white landscape stone and it appears to have REALLY adhered to the surface. I brought in a stone and ran it under my faucet 5 min and even scrubbed it and that yellow doesn't budge. Is this some kind of thing where the chemical when exposed to sunlight changes or something? I don't even know what to do. It's like the whole area looks ruined. Thanks for any info.

Comment: Well if he''s stopping by tomorrow and does not come up with a satisfactory explanation as to how this staining will disappear, or how HE can remove it, make it clear its HIS responsibility to replace any stained white landscape stone at his own cost asap. If he says it will disappear over time, ask how much time - the fact he told you to wash it off indicates he hasn't got a clue what he's talking about, doesn't it, and he's definitely hinting he made up too strong a solution - prodiamine is actually bright yellow.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It helps to know exactly what to say to him. I keep finding online that it doesn't stain but so far I don't believe it. On my flat flagstone yeah, it washes off, but not on the white stone, at all.

Comment: Yea, I read the same thing - but also, I reckon he didn't dilute it  as much as he should (I quote "it came out a little heavy  in the one area" by which he meant oh dear, I messed up) either that or he spilled it and that's his excuse. And yes, it comes off flagstones, diluted at normal rates - but on white stone not diluted properly? If he can't clean it off or its not gone in a week, he needs to replace the stone. And why didn't they put landscape fabric beneath (also called geotextile membrane, NOT paper) though? I'd make 'em redo WITH  membrane cos there will be regrowth of weeds ongoing

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a new landscaper!  Not putting landscape fabric under a patio is a big mistake!

Comment: Update: he came by first thing the next a.m. Said that it will fade over time, but that he'd told his boss that "it's an aesthetic thing, she wants that color gone now" and said he would be back Saturday to "top up" all the rocks that are stained. I'd say he came off worried. He said that he's never had a problem with staining before but that he thinks the chemical might have been more concentrated in the bottom of the tank or something and it "came out too heavy". He said he's a man of his word, that he'd fix it, "I promise, don't worry."